# Receive Slider Output as a Variable

Tags: javascript

I have a slider here that I would like to use-

```html
<main>
    <form oninput="output.value = Math.round(range.valueAsNumber / 1000)">
      <h2>
        Choose the Height of Your Building
      </h2>
      <div class="range">
        <input name="range" type="range" min="0" max="100000">
        <div class="range-output">
          <output class="output" name="output" for="range">
            50
          </output>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>

<button type="button" onclick="">Submit</button>
```

I want to make the output of the slider a variable. For example, if you change the slider to 25, a variable will have a value of 25. Although, I'm not sure what to put inside the onclick function. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the onchange event instead of onclick.  Change your input to this:

```
<input name="range" type="range" min="0" max="100000" onchange="rangeValue=this.value">
```

where `rangeValue` is the name of the global JS variable you wish to assign the new value to.  For example, inside script tags:

```
var rangeValue;
```

Then, you would use the `rangeValue` variable within an event handler for the submit button click.  Something like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="handleClick()">Submit</button>
```

and then within script tags:

```
function handleClick(){
    //do something with rangeValue variable
    console.log(rangeValue);
}
```

Comment: This is what I have, but it says undefined:

Comment: HTML:<main>
    <form oninput="output.value = Math.round(range.valueAsNumber / 1000)">
      <h2>
        Choose the Height of Your Building
      </h2>
      <div class="range">
        <input name="range" type="range" min="0" max="100000" onchange="rangeValue=this.value">
        <div class="range-output">
          <output class="output" name="output" for="range">
            50
          </output>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>

Comment: JS:  <script>

  document.getElementById('write').innerHTML = rangeValue;

  </script>

Comment: It says undefined

Comment: you will need to declare `var rangeValue;` in the javascript code first, somewhere at the global level

Comment: Also the script you have written in the comment is at the global level and will execute on page load, not after the value in the input has changed

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to js. How can I do that?

Comment: I want the end result to be that when you click the button, it will save the output as a variable and go to another page of the website.

Comment: Ok I updated the answer to include an onclick event handler.  I cannot write the whole thing for you.

Comment: Thanks! You saved me!